# Condition (if, else, else if) in YAML

Tags: conditional-statements, nelmio-alice

I use hautelook/AliceBundle to create faker data in YAML, but I would for more consistency of data.

I would like that:

```
gender: <randomElement(['Homme', 'Femme'])>
if $gender == 'Homme'
    title: 'Monsieur'
else if $gender == 'Femme'
    title: 'Madame'
```

I know it's not directly possible in YAML, but I do not know which plugin to use... And how to.

My tools/languages used in my project (Symfony, hautelook/AliceBundle, PHP, YAML)

Comment: As you already indicate yourself that this cannot be done in YAML, using the [tag:yaml] tag is inappropriate, as it is just the format some other tool uses. You should also note that the YAML parser for PHP is a rather poor/restricted one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do that. YAML is data serialization language, not a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

```
- task: TerraformTaskV1@0
${{ if eq(parameters.destroy, false) }}:
  displayName: Terraform Apply
${{ if eq(parameters.destroy, true) }}:
  displayName: Terraform Destroy
inputs:
  provider: 'azurerm'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.destroy, false) }}:
    command: 'apply'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.destroy, true) }}:
    command: 'destroy'
  workingDirectory: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/${{ parameters.environment_name }}${{ parameters.root_directory }}"
  ${{ if eq(parameters.destroy, false) }}:
    commandOptions: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/${{ parameters.environment_name }}${{ parameters.root_directory }}/plan.tfplan"
  ${{ if eq(parameters.destroy, true) }}:
    commandOptions: "--var-file=$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/${{ parameters.environment_name }}${{ parameters.tfvarFile }}"
  environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.service_connection_name }}
```

Comment: Please add more information why this answer solves the question and what the code is doing.

Comment: but when this YAML file is converted to JSON it looks meaning less right? 
with conditions coming as properties, so what would be the way to get them into JSOn format?

Answer (score 0):

yaml files won't include any conditional logic. YAML is a data serialisation language, so it's not contain if/else style executable statements.